# To select range of values between two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has 4 columns  and i want to get a value between two range of values in column .I tried but it returns null.Pls help me to over come the issue.

```
GradeID | FAMin|FAMax| FAGrade|
1       | 37   | 40  |  A1|

SELECT * FROM GradeSystems WHERE FAMin >= 38 AND 38 <= FAMax;
```

Comment: `WHERE 38 BETWEEN FAMin AND FAMax`?

Comment: Can you add some additional information? In the example you added, the answer is correct because the only value that is valid (that will return a non null value) is 38

Answer (score 5):

Your comparison for FAMin was backwards.

```
SELECT * FROM GradeSystems WHERE FAMin <= 38 AND FAMax >= 38;
```

Comment: hi @Tingo, I think u shouldn't use = to both of them (FAMin <= 38 AND FAMax >= 38)